# Angular build fails because it includes components from another angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

When I run `ng build project1 --prod` the build fails with the error message

> `ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class MyComponent in .../project2/app/my.component.ts! Add MyComponent to the NgModule to fix it.`.

This seems pretty straight forward, BUT the mentioned Component is not part of the current Angular project. I defined two projects inside my angular.json and they are not dependent of each other (project1 & project2). I've got a separate shared module which both projects import and use.

The error appeared when I moved a component from project2 to my shared module. My project2 builds fine and the moved components also work fine. `ng serve project1` works without problems. But for some reason, my first project now depends on most components from my second project for no reason. I already searched all my imports for the file without success. Maybe it's related to the fact that the components from project2 extend a component from the shared module?

So is there any way to see where angular thinks it needs this? For example, I see the main chuck was build before - what is angular building when it fails?

Can I exclude this somehow (`tsconfig.app.json` exclude didn't work)?

Comment: Can you show the code on how each project is included in shared module?

Comment: It's the other way around. The shared module is imported in both projects. But the shared module is very basic and has only two declarations and exports.

Comment: Please add the `angular.json` data to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an unused import which itself imported most of the other projects components.

But if anyone still knows a way to see which file caused this kind of error I would still appreciate it and accept it as the final answer. I had to look into every single file to find the wrong import.